# vscode gopls(server): gopkg.in/check.v1: module lookup disabled by GOPROXY=off

Tags: go

My VsCode gopls shows this error ：

```
gopkg.in/check.v1: module lookup disabled by GOPROXY=off
```

I've reloaded VsCode, but they don't seem to help